# "Unfortunately, Setup Wizard has stopped" after factory resetting Yu Yuphoria

Tags: crashes, setup-wizard, micromax-yu-yuphoria

Getting the error message "Unfortunately, Setup Wizard has stopped" repeatedly once after I factory reset my Yu Yuphoria mobile.

Tried it many times and sometimes I could able to set up and proceed, but could not find the settings icon in my menu.

Can someone help me out of this?

Comment: You would need to flash the whole ROM.

Comment: clear temporary memory of your phone and then restart it. It will work for you.

Comment: @RichiRich Doesn't a factory-reset include that? So what would it help then?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to clear cache and dalvik

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! OP writes this happens "after i factory reset". A factory-reset includes clearing cache and dalvik (see the comments on the question itself) – so this doesn't answer the question. Apart from that, your post lacks details on how to do that: especially consider the device being stock and not-rooted, clearing Dalvik might prove difficult :)